# What does #[$] or [$] mean in remix?

Tags: solidity, remix, evm, bytecode

Can someone tell me what the `#[$]` or `[$]` in the remix assembly output means? I assume it's a placeholder for something yet to be determined but am unable to confirm if and what.

For example:

`PUSH #[$] 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

(note: push only takes 1 parameter)

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? I run the demo ballot.sol on remix.ethereum.org and see PUSH FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF and other variants.

Comment: @DaveIdito Take a look around tag 6, I see it there for Ballot.sol

Comment: Interesting! @DAnsermino, you are correct.